# Получение состояния объекта (поля и значения). Рефлексия

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть некоторый класс Analyser. Написал метод, который по полученному объекту должен вывести его состояние - список всех полей в классе с их значениями:

```
public static String classInstance(Object obj) throws 
ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Class c = Class.forName("Analyser"); //ошибка
    Object o = c.newInstance();
    Analyser a = (Analyser) o;

    for (Field field: a.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
    {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(o);
        if (value != null)
        {
            sb.append(field.getName() + " = " + value);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

В main я хочу вывести это в консоль, но не совсем понимаю как.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException 
{
    System.out.println(Analyser.classInstance(Analyser.class.getClass()));
   //ошибка
}
```

Плюс получаются ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Analyser
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at Analyser.classInstance(Analyser.java:195)
at Analyser.main(Analyser.java:272)
```

Растолкуйте пожалуйста, как сделать это правильно. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: package укажите перед именем класса.

Comment: @АлександрПоташев это не влияет

Comment: Проверил у себя. Без указания package получаю КлассНотФаундЭксепшн, с указанием - норма.

Comment: @АлександрПоташев, указал имя пакета в обоих строках, где ошибки, на консоли просто ничего не появляется

Comment: Скопипастил ваш код, изменил Class c = Class.forName("ru.net.arh.reflect.Analyser") и все работает.

Comment: Аа, у вас в main что-то странное. И зачем вам параметр obj в методе, он там не используется.
В main я вызываю так System.out.println(classInstance(new Object()));

Comment: @АлександрПоташев, такие же ошибки получаются в тех же строках

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74160/discussion-between---and-yashi).